# Identification of PE section characteristic

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, memory, portable-executable

I need to identify, whether a given pointer is a pointer to a writable or non-writable memory.
I think, it might be identified by that the pointer points to a PE section, and the section has not the IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE flag set.

Is there any simple way, how to obtain the section characteristic based on just pointer? (I don't want to parse the PE in runtime, I expect, there is some direct way.

Comment: Can you be clear about what you have at hand? You talk about a PE file, but don't want to read or parse the file. That seems odd. How will you be able to learn anything without consulting the file? Or are you asking about a scenario where the PE file backs a module that has been loaded into a process? And is the process which loaded the module, the process where your code executes? Please remember that we have no idea what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: Until the PE has been loaded, it doesn't have an address anyway, and you can have pointers to something that's not in memory (yet). This question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`VirtualQuery` will give you the required information, if the PE file has been loaded into memory. It doesn't make sense to have a pointer to something that's not loaded in memory, so this is probably sufficient for your purpose.

Since VirtualQuery works on pages, round down the pointer to the previous page boundary, and set the length to check to just one page.